# C-^ not registering

Tags: key-bindings, keystrokes

As the title suggests, I cannot enter `C-^` in emacs.  It doesn't work in `org-mode` nor does it register anything when I try to enter it into `describe-key`.

If it helps at all I am on mac using emacs version 26.1

Comment: Are you using Emacs in terminal mode? If so, it's likely that `C-^` isn't available. Please say how you start Emacs (e.g. `emacs -nw` for terminal).

Comment: I am using spacemacs so it is a stand alone app on mac.  I believe this would be windowed/gui mode?

Comment: what happens when you run C-h k C-^?

Comment: As I said, running `describe-key` (C-h k) does nothing.  The minibuffer pops up but then nothing registers when I try to hammer on C-^ (technically C-S-6)

Comment: AFAIK, `C-^` is not used by any mode (including Org mode): my emacs reports that it is undefined. OTOH, it does see it. Presumably, in your case something "eats" that key before emacs has a chance to get to it. Check keyboard shortcuts for your GUI but it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: Hmm, that is strange.  Maybe it is because I am on spacemacs, but I have `C-^` bound to  `org-up-element`  (org version `9.2.3`), what is it bound to on yours?  I looked but I can't find anything related to the GUI that would be eating `C-^`